# Add path alias for typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsconfig, craco, tsconfig-paths

I am using create-react-app as scaffolding and tsconfig-paths as extension of my tsconfig because create-react-app is removing my paths when ran. I have been using this setup for a year now and I have no problems with it but recently when I created a project from scratch, it doesn't work anymore

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig-paths.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "types": [
      "cypress"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "downlevelIteration": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig-paths.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "paths": {
            "components/*": ["./components/*"],
            "constants/*": ["./constants/*"],
            "pages/*": ["./pages/*"],
            "assets/*": ["./assets/*"],
            "actions/*": ["./actions/*"],
            "reducers/*": ["./reducers/*"],
            "layouts/*": ["./layouts/*"],
            "routes/*": ["./routes/*"],
            "utils/*": ["./utils/*"],
            "theme/*": ["./theme/*"],
            "api": ["./api"],
            "hooks": ["./hooks"],
            "formdocuments/*": ["./formdocuments/*"],
      "enums/*": ["./enums/*"]
        }
    }
}
```

scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

Answer (score 3):

You must install `craco-alias` first. you have to has `craco.config.js` file.
The file should be like this:

```
// craco.config.js
const CracoAlias = require('craco-alias')
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        {
            plugin: CracoAlias,
            options: {
                source: 'tsconfig',
                // baseUrl SHOULD be <specified></specified>
                // plugin does not take it from tsconfig
                baseUrl: './src',
                /* tsConfigPath should point to the file where "baseUrl" and "paths" 
              are specified*/
                tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.paths.json',
            },
        },
    ],
}
```

Then you must create `tsconfig.paths.json` file in root of project. This file has path alias such as:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "paths": {
            "@components/*": ["components/*"]
        }
    }
}
```

in tsconfig.json file that created in root of project, you must extends `tsconfig.paths.json`.

tsconfig file has below content:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

suppose that you have `components` folder that inside of it has `Sample/index.tsx` directory. you can import Sample component by

```
import Sample from '@components/Sample'
```

Answer (score 2):

## Here is a work around

Path alias are no longer supported

**you can do this instead**, To simplify import paths, you can directly import files relative to the `src` directory

go to your `tsconfig.json` file add base URL to be `"."`

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl":".",
    ...
```

then you can directly import stuff from the `src` directory

```
import Myfile from "src/myfile.js"
```